# Keyboard shortcuts get randomly reset

Tags: 11.10, gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm facing a rather weird issue in the past few days after doing a clean install of Ubuntu Oneiric (w/ gnome-shell) on my recently-bought Asus U36SD.

I set up my keyboard shortcuts using *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*, and some of them get randomly reset.

Most of my shortcuts include the win key (otherwise listed in the keyboard shortcuts as Mod4), but those containing only Mod4 +  get reset every two-three reboots.

For instance, Mod4 + T (for terminal), gets reset to the standard Ctrl + Alt + T, while Shift + Mod4 + W (for browser) doesn't (I've set up the latter with the Shift key, because it seems that Mod4 + W didn't get intercepted at all. Something similar goes for Mod4 + E *for gedit*, which only worked once or twice).

I have no idea if this is a Ubuntu specific issue, or it's related to gnome-shell or even with my current hardware.

Has this happened to any of you? If so, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome shell on Asus 1225B netbook. I have another Laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 Unity where this problem does NOT occur. So I think this is a gnome shell issue.

I use a bunch of configuration tools on my netbook, I guess that one of them is also able to change the shortcut configuration, but has the default one saved, so maybe you reset the shortcut configuration using this tool to change login sound or whatever. I have my netbook for a few days so I was not able to check this.